# DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name Customer

Tags: c#, data-binding

```
 protected void Button_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    string[] readtext = File.ReadAllLines(path);


    StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string s in readtext)
    {
        strbuild.Append(s);
        strbuild.AppendLine();

    }
    ListBox1.DataValueField = strbuild.ToString();
    ListBox1.DataTextField = strbuild.ToString();
    ListBox1.DataSource = strbuild.ToString();
    ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Here I am uploading the file which contains the details of customer. When I select the file it is showing the error like

> DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name XXX.

What I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think StringBuilder is not efficient in this scenario. Best option is creating a class for customer with properties for `name` and `id` then create a List from the input Data and bind it to the list. Here the file format is unknown and you are not provided any details regarding the file. So here i show you one example of how to bind listbox from a List;

```
        List<string> strList = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Sujith\Desktop\sujith\Allcredentials.txt").ToList();
        ListBox1.DataSource = strList;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine. But I have one issue like                                        "string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    string[] readtext = File.ReadAllLines(path);"                                                               This line is selecting the complete line, but I need to select the Single value at a time. How its possible..??

Comment: This link will help you to do that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding does not work that way. You have to create List then store every line of it

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in readtext)
{
    strbuild.Add(s);
}
ListBox1.DataSource = strList;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

or you can just simply put the string array from what you read

```
ListBox1.DataSource = readText;
```

Comment: Thanks Gilang....Its working fine..Thanks for Your kind helpp...                               "string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    string[] readtext = File.ReadAllLines(path);"                                                     This Line is selecting lines in a file. But here I need to select only one value in a line. How Its possible..??

Answer (score 0):

`Gilang`'s answer should work, but there is a special class designed to be used with binding - [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code should look like this:

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<string>(readText);
ListBox1.DataSource = bindingList;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Thus, all changes (add or remove) in the item list of the list box are properly caught in the data source - you actually have `two way binding`.

**Note:** try to use meaningful names for your variables, otherwise the code will become very hard to read when it grows:

```
`ListBox1` -> `lstCustomers` or `CustomersList` 
`readText` -> `readLines` or `customerNames`
```